# Проблемы с ScrollView и LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

При добавлении ScrollView и LinearLayout всё элементы перемещаться в другие места.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fon"
    tools:context=".osn">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58.86dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="429.13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/log" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="317dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="86dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="ПРИВЕТ"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Наслаждайся учебой Будь внимателен Делай хорошо"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="499dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/but"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Войти в аккаунт"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="704dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Еще нет аккаунта?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.976"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="704dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Зарегистрируйтесь"
        android:textColor="@color/gr2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: В какие такие другие места?

Comment: Конечно, все view внутри LinearLayout следуют друг за другом, они теперь не внутри констрэйна, и привязки к нему не работают.